# iOS - How to call NSInteger variable in button title?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've been trying to change button title through variable value but I am not getting it.

```
NSInteger value1=4;
[butttonIcon setTitle:@"value1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not set integer value directly to button title text.

You have to first convert it to NSString and than set it to button title text.

like,

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", value1];

[butttonIcon setTitle:string forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

So now it is NSString value and it will display your value1 as title.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Here the code you wrote, actually setting "Value1" as the title of your button. If you want to display the `NSInteger` variable as your button title, then first of all you need to convert the `NSInteger` to `NSString`, because the intake argument for button's title is `NSString.
So first convert the`NSInteger`to`NSString`, then use the string as your button's title. You can do that by following ways.

```
NSInteger value1=4;
NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", value1];
[butttonIcon setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming in your case you want the title to be 4, just use this for the string:

```
[@(value1) stringValue]
```